# Does this proof method work and/or exist?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

I have a new proof method that im not sure if it works and proves the result, its like proof by contradiction, but rather then obtaining a contradiction and disproving the result, your asumption would satisfy the equation and hence prove the assumption e.g

If you know for a fact and have proven that

$$\begin{align}P(k)&=g(1)(k)p(k+1)-g(2)(k)p(k+2)+…+g(n-k-2)(k)p(k+(n-k-2))\\&-g(n-k-1)(k)p(k+(n-k-1))+g(n-k)(k)\end{align}$$

Where $g(n-k-m)(k)$ and $p(k+m)$ are some functions, if we assume that $p(k+m)=g(n-k-m)(k)$ then…

$g(1)p(k+1)=g(n-k-1)p(k+(n-k-1))$

$g(2)p(k+2)=g(n-k-2)p(k+(n-k-2))$

Etc..

Then in our equation everything cancels out and we are left with $p(k)=g(n-k)(k)$ which satisfies our assumption for $m=0.$

But we know our originial eqaution is true so does that mean the assumption is true because it satisfies thr equation that is true, much like how many if $x+2=8$  and we assume $x=6$ and it satisfies the equation then it prove $x=6$ is a solution?

Comment: I suspect some typos in your first equation: (1) In the next-to-last term, I think you mean $p(k+(n-k-1))$, not $p(k+(k-n-1))$; (2) Do you intend for the terms to have alternating signs? There is an inconsistent appearance of "$+$" and "$-$" between terms

Answer (score 1):

If you make the substitution and it works, that means it's one solution to the equation you found. But substituting $x=6$ into $x+2=8$ is not the only kind of example.

Imagine you substituted $x=6$ into $x^2-5x=6$. You would get a true statement, but you would be missing another solution: $x=-1$.

Or imagine you had a functional equation: $f(x+y) = f(x) f(y)$. You could substitute $f(x) = 0$ and get a true statement. However, $f(x) = 2^x$ is another solution, and there's many others.

Depending on your situation, getting a single solution might be enough. But you have not proved that your guess is the *only* possible thing that could be true.

Comment: @MPW yes the signes are alternating thanks for spotting the mistakes changes have been made

Comment: thank you, but its not that im looking for a solution, its that im looking to prove the statement that i assumed. In context ive defined g(k) and p(k) in such a way that i plan on proving thr asusmption, but i know that the following equation is true and hence i tried to use thay equation to prove the assumption. There could exist other solutions but im not entiled to solve for those other solutions, im just trying to prove this one assumtion/ statement is correct

Comment: In that case, you have not yet proved it.

Comment: You've shown that you've found something that is consistent with your assumption (i.e. it's a necessary condition), but this isn't the same as showing that it's sufficient.